# Storing a series of tokens for later evaluation

Tags: expansion, loops

Is it possible to expand the tokens in a string as though they were typed at that point in the source file? I'm trying to do something like this:

```
\begin{vmatrix}
\@for\tmpone:=a,b,c\do{%
  \def\thisrow{}%
  \@for\tmptwo:=d,e,f\do{%
    \expandafter\xdef\expandafter\thisrow{\thisrow & \string\foo{\tmpone}{\tmptwo}}
  }
  \thisrow
}
\end{vmatrix}
```

The difference is that I want the string that is now `thisrow` to be expanded, not just reproduced as a string. Is something like that possible?

Note that `\foo` is not necessarily a "robust" command.

**ADDENDUM**
Some have asked me to be more specific, and I think the problem is things like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand*{\foo}[3]{%
  \def\silly{#3}%
  % more code
  \left(\frac{\partial #1}{\partial #2}\right)_{#3}}%
\begin{document}
\[ \begin{vmatrix}
\makeatletter
    \@for\tmpone:=f,g,h\do{%
      \def\thisrow{}%
      \@for\tmptwo:=x,y,z\do{%
        \expandafter\xdef\expandafter\thisrow\expandafter{\thisrow & \noexpand\foo{\tmpone}{\tmptwo}{oeu}}
      }
      \thisrow \\[1.25ex]
    }
\makeatother
  \end{vmatrix}
\]
\end{document}
```

If I comment out the `\def` line in the definition of `\foo`, it works.

Any construct within `\foo` that defines a macro inside it seems to cause either an undefined control sequence error or an extra "}" error.

@DavidCarlisle answered my question of whether it's possible to take a series of tokens that look to human beings to be expandable TeX macros (but were concatenated using `\string`) and expand them, and the answer is, as I feared, "no."

Comment: you probably meant \noexpand not \string before \foo but hard to guess

Comment: Can you please tell more about your aim? What's `\foo` supposed to do?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle You are correct, \noexpand is what I wanted, but the example with "string" actually did what I wanted, sans expansion, so I used that to explain what I was trying to do. The question is actually two of them: (1) Is it possible to expand something that has already been categorized as a "string" (using \string) and (2) Is there a way to have an arbitrary, possibly context-dependent, command that is not expanded until I want it to be.

This gives me something to work with, at least.

Comment: (1) no, anything produced by `\string` is catcode 12 characters and there is noting to expand. (2) yes that is the normal tex behaviour of any macro.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @egreg I am working on a command for the thermodynamics package to typeset Jacobian determinants, so "\foo" in this case would be the "\Partial" command in that package to make partial derivatives. It doesn't expand "cleanly" in this context, which has made this task tricky. I was also asking question (1) in my reply above, though, which is whether it's possible to string together an expression and then evaluate it, much like one can do in the shell with "eval" or in Python with the eval() intrinsic.

Comment: @karlh Probably you can get more help if you show an example of the expected output and, maybe, the syntax you'd like.

Comment: you can use `\scantokens` to re-parse a string but it's a tricky beast that will bite the unwary and the chance that your real aim is best served by using `\string` then re-parsing is essentially zero. `\noexpand` holds the token but keeps it as a token, which is much more useful in almost all cases.

Comment: Just define `\Partial` as a `\protected` command then it will not expand in an xdef and you do not need `\noexpand` or `\string` at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `\protected\def\foo` and no `\expadafter`, no `\noexpand`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\protected\def\foo#1#2#3{%
  \def\silly{#3}%
  % more code
  \left(\frac{\partial #1}{\partial \lower.2ex\vbox{}#2}\right)_{#3}}%
\begin{document}
\[ \begin{vmatrix}
\makeatletter
    \@for\tmpone:=f,g,h\do{%
      \def\thisrow{}%
      \@for\tmptwo:=x,y,z\do{%
        \xdef\thisrow{\ifx\thisrow\empty\else \thisrow &\fi\foo{\tmpone}{\tmptwo}{oeu}}
      }
      \if\tmpone h \thisrow\else \thisrow \\[1.25ex] \fi
    }
\makeatother
  \end{vmatrix}
\]
\end{document}
```

Your way of thinking is closer to plain TeX than LaTeX, so maybe you will be happy with plain TeX or OpTeX (were `\foreach` macro is ready to use):

```
\fontfam[lm]
\protected\def\jelement#1#2{\displaystyle{\partial#1\overwithdelims()\partial#2}}
\def\jacobian#1#2{\def\jdata{}
   \foreach #1\do{\let\jrow=\ignoreit
      \foreach #2\do{\edef\jrow{\jrow & \jelement{##1}{####1}}}
      \edef\jdata{\ifx\jdata\empty \else\jdata \cr\noalign{\kern.5ex} \fi \jrow}
    }
    \left|\matrix{\jdata}\right|
}

$$
\jacobian{fgh}{xyz}
$$

\bye
```

Comment: This led me to an answer that I understand; thanks! I must admit I had never seen `protected` before (or at least if I did, I didn't know what it meant). I understand what it does now---it's basically an improved version of `DeclareRobustCommand`---but I had trouble finding it in any documentation. Is it relatively new, or just obscure?

Comment: `\protected` is an eTeX primitive command, it is here since about 1992. eTeX primitives are part of all TeX engines used today. See, for example, my document TeX in a Nutshell  http://petr.olsak.net/ftp/olsak/optex/tex-nutshell.pdf , page 17.

Answer (score 4):

`\expandafter\thisrow{\thisrow`

applies expansion to `{` which is not expandable, you want

`\expandafter\thisrow\expandafter{\thisrow`

Comment: This got me one step closer, but not quite there yet. ;-) I actually had this in a previous version, but given that I was using \string, it didn't make any difference. It does when \noexpand is used.

Comment: @karlh as you provided no test example it's hard to give any more steps than this first step.

Comment: Aha! The dual `\expandafter` answers something I never asked. Never realized that the first would try to expand the brace.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{thermodynamics}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\newJacobian}{mmm}
 {% #1 = list of functions, #2 = list of variables, #3 = subscript
  \begin{vmatrix}
  \thermodynamics_jacobian:nnn { #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
  \end{vmatrix}
 }

\seq_new:N \l__thermodynamics_row_seq
\seq_new:N \l__thermodynamics_full_seq

\cs_new_protected:Nn \thermodynamics_jacobian:nnn
 {
  \seq_clear:N \l__thermodynamics_full_seq
  \clist_map_inline:nn { #1 }
   {
    \seq_clear:N \l__thermodynamics_row_seq
    \clist_map_inline:nn { #2 }
     {
      \seq_put_right:Nn \l__thermodynamics_row_seq { \displaystyle\Partial{##1}{####1}{#3} }
     }
    \seq_put_right:Nx \l__thermodynamics_full_seq { \seq_use:Nn \l__thermodynamics_row_seq { & } }
   }
  \seq_use:Nn \l__thermodynamics_full_seq { \\[2ex] }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\[
\newJacobian{F,G,H}{x,y,z}{P}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: My LaTeX3 knowledge is not sufficient to understand your example, but it does work perfectly! I have some reading to do to understand what things like `\seq_new:N` mean, but thank you very much.

Comment: Your example has prompted me to start reading the expl3, xparse, and interface3 documentation and (someday) translate my packages and classes to use the L3 programming layer. There's lots to learn, but it looks to be worth it. Thanks!